Use media like query to detect overflow
How can I react to an HTML element overflowing in CSS?
I want to show an alternative smaller element, when an element does not fit horizontaly.
I don't want to use media queries, because afaik media queries need a fixed screen width to compare with. But I don't know when I need to switch to the smaller element, because I don't know how much screen width my element would need.
If that is not possible in pure CSS, is there an approach, that involves JavaScript?
If that is not feasible either, then how do web developers tackle this problem otherwise?
(I'm not a web developer. I'm a senior software developer, but I've done very little front end work until now.)
I want to build my own responsive navbar similar to bootstrap navbar, that switches to a burger menu, when the screen becomes to narrow. But even there I have seen, that the switching is not always accurate. (Switching happens to late to early)

no code => no chocolate. but you can take a look at containerqueries

CSS cannot detect overflow and I'm very doubtful if container queries would help here. I believe you need javascript.

Frankly this sounds like an XY problem. if you can provide a [mcve] (not the word minimal, we might be able to see a way round your issue. Media queries aren't that complicated and you might be missing something fairly simple.

It seems at first like a good idea to build a responsive menu which switches to a hamburger when the menu items don’t fit on one line. But actually, it’s not. If someone adds ten menu items, suddenly you’d get a hamburger on a desktop screen, which isn’t what people expect. People expect hamburgers on phones, but not desktops. Just use a media query to control your hamburger, that’s what we mostly do. In your desktop layout, just allow the menu to wrap if it won’t fit on one line.

try css @container rule
is like a mediaquery but specify per element

How does this help detect overflow? [Text may be all 'thin' characters or all 'fat' characters or an unknown mixture...]

If an element desidered min-width larger as @container width, the element is overflow. Example: https://codepen.io/batlabor/pen/GRbNVvV

I think it would help if you could provide a runnable snippet which shows how, regardless of the width of the element (note, as OP has said, the width is not known in advance), the overflow will be detected by CSS. I'm afraid I still suspect this is not possible.

detect, reacts... are all of terms of by OP,
css is a declerative "langauge".
btw I show a valid solution above

I have tried your codepen with different size content (text length) and it makes no difference, I still don't see how the CSS is sensing overflow. Please put a snippet into your question and explain how it senses the overflow.
